# Find words that rhyme

Tags: code-golf, natural-language

## Challenge

Joe the rapper is struggling with rhyming words in his lyrics. He needs your help.

For this situation, we will use rhymes where the last syllable in a word is the same as the other word (spelled the same).

When Joe inputs a word, the program will read a list of words from a file and output those that rhyme with Joe's word.

To show that the program works, we will only need to use a small list.

txt File:

```
hello
joe
crew
flow
time
apple
heart
glow
rhyme
art
jello
grew
doe
flue
blow
smart
dime
cat
slime
show
bedtime
clue
grime
toe
dart
cart
brew
snow
prime
hat
chart
lime
blue
knew
lunchtime
restart
```

## Examples

Input: `snow`

Output: `blow flow glow show` *Note- Should not output the input*

Input: `fart`

Output: `restart art dart cart chart smart heart` *Note- Should work for inputs not in list*

Input: `crime`

Output: `time slime prime grime dime lime bedtime lunchtime` *Note- Should work for all syllables*

## Rules

1. Should output all words that rhyme with input

   *does not need to output rhymes with different letters Ex: `Crime` should not output `rhyme`*
2. Should not output the input
3. Should work with inputs not in the list
4. Should work will all syllables

Shortest Bytes Wins!

Comment: Define "rhyme". Does "bedtime" rhyme with "clue"?

Comment: See comments on http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/7014/194 for a suggestion as to how to make "rhyme" well-specified.

Comment: @Peter I think JoshK is looking for something simpler than phonetic rhyming. `does not need to output rhymes with differet letters` and `snow` --> `blow flow glow show` (but not `toe`) Anyway, Josh, a proper definition is required. Given examples follow the rule of last vowel and all consonants after it (this works for `chart & heart` but would fail for `chat & heat`.) As shown by Kenny Lau's example,  matching the whole of the last vowel cluster (and any following  consonants) may be better but would make `heart` invalid. Voting to close until resolved. (personally I'd get rid of `heart`)

Comment: As you haven't been here that long, I'll point out that the reason for close voting is nothing personal, it's to temporarily stop the posting of answers before the rules have been fully clarified (as is happening right now.) You could try posting your next challeng in the sandbox for feedback first before posting on the main site http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/2140/15599

Comment: Do `though`, `through`, and `rough` rhyme?

Answer (score 1):

## Ruby, 68 bytes

FGITW. Full program, takes file and word from command line: `ruby script.rb words.txt "hello"`.

Assumes the last syllable (or rather, the section of the syllable to match against for the purposes of rhyming) is at least 2 characters long, or more if there are extra vowels before that.

```
f,w=$*
w=~/[aeiou]*..$/
puts open(f).map(&:chomp).grep(/#{$&}$/)-[w]
```

Answer (score 1):

### JavaScript (ES6), 67 bytes

```
(a,w)=>a.filter(s=>s!=w&s.endsWith(w.replace(/.*([aeiou].)/,"$1")))
```

Function that accepts an array of words and an input word as parameters. Uses the definition of rhyme as the substring of the word starting at the last vowel before the last letter.

```js
a=
(a,w)=>a.filter(s=>s!=w&s.endsWith(w.replace(/.*([aeiou].)/,"$1")))
;
u=w=>r.value=a(f.value.split`\n`,w).join`\n`
```

```html
File:
<textarea rows=5 id=f>
hello
joe
crew
flow
time
apple
heart
glow
rhyme
art
jello
grew
doe
flue
blow
smart
dime
cat
slime
show
bedtime
clue
grime
toe
dart
cart
brew
snow
prime
hat
chart
lime
blue
knew
lunchtime
restart
</textarea>
<br>
Word:
<input oninput="u(this.value)">
<br>
Rhymes:
<textarea rows=5 id=r>
</textarea>
```

Comment: What is your definition of rhyme? You should state it in English (not just code) in the answer. Better still, wait for the OP to clarify the rules before posting.